# Why are the phosphate ion and hydrogen phosphate not conjugate acid/base pairs of each other?

Tags: acid-base

> (e) Identify in the following reaction the Bronsted-Lowry acid and its conjugate base
>
> $$\ce{PO4^3- + HNO3 -> NO3- + HPO4^2-}$$

Both $\ce{PO4^3-}$ and $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ differ by a $\ce{H+}$ ion so why aren't they conjugate acid base pairs?.

Comment: $\ce{PO4^_3-}$ is not an acid. It is a base. So the only acid in this reaction is $\ce{HNO3}$. Its conjugate base is the ion$\ce{NO3^-}$. The ion $\ce{HPO4^-} $ is the conjugated acid of the base $\ce{PO4^{3–}}$. It is not the acid creating the rection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query seems to be a product of misunderstanding the problem in question.

The question asks the following,

> (e) Identify in the following reaction the **Bronsted-Lowry acid** and its conjugate base
>
> $$\ce{PO4^3- + HNO3 -> NO3- + HPO4^2-}$$

Now, your reasoning is correct. $\ce{PO4^3-}$ and $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ are in fact conjugate acid/base pairs. However, the question doesn't ask for that. Rather it asks for the **Bronsted-Lowry acid** (in this reaction specifically).

According to [*The IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology* **2014**](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.C01266), a conjugate acid-base pair is defined as follows.

> The Brønsted acid $\ce{BH+}$ formed on protonation of a base B is called the conjugate acid of B, and B is the conjugate base of $\ce{BH+}$. (The conjugate acid always carries one unit of positive charge more than the base, but the absolute charges of the species are immaterial to the definition.) For example: the Brønsted acid $\ce{HCl}$ and its conjugate base $\ce{Cl−}$ constitute a **conjugate acid–base pair.**
>
> (emphasis mine)

Now, a Bronsted acid is defined within the same book as the following,

> A molecular entity capable of donating a hydron (proton) to a base, (i.e. a 'hydron donor') or the corresponding chemical species. For example: $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{H3O+}$, $\ce{CH3CO2H}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{HSO4−}$, $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{CH3OH}$, $\ce{NH3}$

In this specific question, the hydron donor is $\ce{HNO3}$ and therefore, it is the Bronsted acid. Both pairs - $\ce{PO4^3-}$ and $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ as well as $\ce{HNO3}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ - are conjugate acid/base pairs though.